# how the decimal digits is decided in ToString(CultureInfo.NumberFormat)

Tags: c#, decimal

I met an issue about formatting decimal using CultureInfo in C# today.
I have a decimal fValue has a value of 999, when it runs fValue.ToString(CurrentCulture.NumberFormat) 999.0000 is returned. 
While debugging in VS I can get the following values in the Watch window:

```
fValue //returns 999
fValue.ToString(CurrentCulture.NumberFormat)  //the issue returns 999.0000 
(999M).ToString(CurrentCulture.NumberFormat)  //returns 999
CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits //returns 2
```

Why the second value returns 999.0000 rather than 999 or 999.00? Sorry for my crap English someone please help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with the en-US culture.  What is the current culture being used in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Using CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits property you will get the number of decimal digits for Decimal type. 999M type is typeof(Decimal), and it is considered as Currency.

Answer (score 0):

The Decimal struct preserves the precision of the values after parsing from a string, and also as computations are performed.  The ToString() method correctly indicates the actual internal precision of the value, regardless of which culture is being used.

However, the debugger appears to display the value in its simplest form instead of showing what ToString() would return, which makes things confusing to say the least.